# Tcl finding min value in a textfile

Tags: tcl, min

i have one Textfile with thousands of values and some alphanumerical chars like this:

```
\Test1
    +3.00000E-04
    +5.00000E-04
    +4.00000E-04
```

now i want to scan this file and write the values into variables.

```
set path "C:/test.txt"
set in  [open $path r]

while {[gets $in line] != -1} { 
set Cache [gets $in line]      
if { $Cache < $Cache }  {
set lowest "$Cache"
}
}
```

has anybody an idea? im getting a alert which tells me the Directory couldnt deleted?!

br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the core math function `tcl::mathfunc::min`. If there is "junk" (i.e. lines that contain text that aren't numbers), you can filter those lines out first:

```
set numbers {}
set f [open test.txt]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {[string is double -strict $line]} {
        lappend numbers [string trim $line]
    }
}
close $f
tcl::mathfunc::min {*}$numbers
# => +3.00000E-04
```

If every line is a valid double precision floating point number, you can dispense with the filtering:

```
set f [open test.txt]
set numbers [split [string trim [read $f]]]
close $f
tcl::mathfunc::min {*}$numbers
# => +3.00000E-04
```

If you can use the Tcllib module `fileutil`, which is easy to pick up from [the Tcllib site](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/4709390bcbd91507) if not available on your installation (it is included in the ActiveTcl installation already), you can simplify the code somewhat:

```
package require fileutil 

set numbers {}
::fileutil::foreachLine line test.txt {
    if {[string is double -strict $line]} {
        lappend ::numbers [string trim $line]
    }
}
tcl::mathfunc::min {*}$numbers
```

or

```
package require fileutil 

tcl::mathfunc::min {*}[split [string trim [::fileutil::cat test.txt]]]
```

Documentation:
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm),
[Mathematical functions for Tcl expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm)

Comment: nice, but how can it run if i have in this Textfile some alphanumerical chars?